# Can the compiler tell when a `break` is never reached

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
fn make_guess() -> u32 {
    loop {
        let mut guess = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
            .ok()
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => return num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please input a number!");
                continue;
            }
        };
        break;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the compiler complains about:

```
expected `u32`,
  found `()`
```

Seemingly the `break;` results in this returning a void value. However, there is no way for the `break;` to be reached because of the `return` and `continue`.

In fact, if I remove the `break;` this works fine.

Is this a bug in the compiler or intended for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `loop` expression that doesn't contain a `break` expression evaluates to `!` (i.e. it diverges), so it is compatible with all types.

```
fn main() {
    let _x: u32 = loop {}; // this compiles
}
```

On the other hand, a `loop` with a `break` returns `()`, so it is only compatible with the `()` type.

```
fn main() {
    let _x: u32 = loop { break; }; // mismatched types: expected `u32`,  found `()`
}
```

In your `make_guess` function, the compiler adds an implicit `return` before the `loop` expression. `!` is compatible with `u32`, but `()` is not. (This implicit `return` seems to occur for all diverging expressions, even if they end with a `;`.) Adding a `break` statement in the loop changes the type of the `loop` expression. It does not matter that the `break` is unreachable.

*Heads up to @ker for noticing that the type of a `loop` changes based on the presence or absence of a `break` expression in its body.*

Comment: I mistyped that; I have edited the question to move the `break;` where it is supposed to go. When I build this code, I get an error - not a warning (rust 1.4)

Comment: Yes, you get an error because the compiler thinks there's a path that returns `()` when the `break` is present. Replace `break;` with something else (e.g. `let x = 0;`) and you'll see the warning I'm talking about.

Comment: So returning `()` is an error vs. returning a value

Comment: Correct. A loop expression normally evaluates to `()`, but the compiler ignores that when it determines that the loop can never end. Or something like that.

Comment: a loop without break returns `!`, meaning it diverges

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code might not return a `u32`. The best way to keep your code idiomatic to rust would be to make your return type an `Option<T>` Which is an enum with two members `Some(T)`, and `None` which means that the function may, or may not return a value.

```
fn make_guess() -> Option<u32> {
    loop {
        let mut guess = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
            .ok()
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => return Some(num),
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please input a number!");
                continue;
            }
        };
        break;
    }
    None
}
```

Comment: The function as you've written it will never return `None`, as the `break` is unreachable, because all branches of the `match` diverge.

Comment: @FrancisGagné The problem with the code above is not that that the break is unreachable. It's that all return points as far as the compiler is concerned is not complete. The compiler can't tell that the function ends at the match statement.

Comment: The compiler can absolutely tell that the function ends at the match statement. Compile your function ([in a complete program](http://is.gd/qaEymM)) and you'll see a warning because the `break` is unreachable. Therefore, the path that returns `None` is also unreachable. Sure, your code makes all types match, but in this specific function, it's not necessary because the `break` shouldn't be there in the first place.